# How to pass variable constrains while minimizing function with multiple variables and return the variables?

Tags: matlab, optimization

Assume I have a function with 5 variables, and each one have a range constrains. I want to find the minimum of a function, as well as the values of those 5 variables which are needed to obtain that minimum value in that function. I am using the fminsearch.

```
func = @(x, y, z, k, m) (--some-function-which-depends-to-those-5-variable);
```

Assume I have above function that I want to minimize.

```
range_x = [12, 24];
range_y = [13.3, 30.2];
range_z = [1.4, 4.7];
range_k = [1.2, 1.4];
range_m = [4.12, 12.2];
```

and the above ranges.

```
??? = fminsearch(@(x) func(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5)), ???)
```

I am currently using fminsearch function. However, I stucked the point that how can I use ranges and how can I extract the min value / and all those 5 variables which gives this result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`fminsearch` as per the documentation, is for unconstrained minimization, i.e. you don't put limits on the variables.

`fmincon` instead, is for constrained minimization.

Comment: Hello Ander,
I do not have constrains on variables depending on each other, and I am having trouble to understand how can I give A and b parameters in my case. Can you explain a bit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The parameters of interests to you are `ub` and `lb`. I believe you can just make `A` and `b` zero, that makes the constraint true for any `x`.